# dplyr: Handing over multiple variables to group_by in a function

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I have a function with `dplyr::summarize`. How can I hand over more than one variable to it?

Example:

```
myfunction <- function(mydf, grp) {

  library(dplyr)

  grp <- enquo(grp)

  result <- mydf %>% 
    group_by(!! grp) %>% 
    summarise(sum = sum(x))

  result

}

# works
myfunction(df, grp1) 

# doesn't work
myfunction(df, c(grp1, grp2))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we pass multiple variables, pass that as a string and make use of `group_by_at`

```
myfunction <- function(mydf, grp, xvar) {  
  mydf %>%       
    group_by_at(grp) %>%
    summarise(sum = sum({{xvar}}))
 }



myfunction(mtcars, "am", mpg)
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#     am   sum
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1     0  326.
#2     1  317.
myfunction(mtcars, c("am", "gear"), mpg)
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   am [2]
#     am  gear   sum
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     0     3 242. 
#2     0     4  84.2
#3     1     4 210. 
#4     1     5 107.
```

---

In case, we want to pass the groups as showed in the OP's post, one way is to convert with `enexpr` and evaluate (`!!!`)

```
myfunction <- function(mydf, grp, xvar) {  
   grp <- as.list(rlang::enexpr(grp))
   grp <- if(length(grp) > 1) grp[-1] else grp

   mydf %>%
        group_by(!!! grp) %>%
        summarise(sum = sum({{xvar}}))

 }

myfunction(mtcars, am, mpg)
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#     am   sum
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1     0  326.
#2     1  317.
myfunction(mtcars, c(am, gear), mpg)
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   am [2]
#     am  gear   sum
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     0     3 242. 
#2     0     4  84.2
#3     1     4 210. 
#4     1     5 107.
```